# android - sharing files from other apps to my app (react native but is probably not a react native issue)

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent

My RN app uses react-native-share-menu to accept files shared from other android apps.
This works fine when sharing from the photo gallery for instance, but for the **generic 'Files' app** on **some** devices (not all devices or on emulators) this sharing does not work well. The intent is sent and my app is launched or comes to the foreground as it is supposed to, **but the app state seems to be 'reset'** somehow - resulting in my app performing strangely.

So My question is primarily an Android question, probably to do with Intents and receiving Intents -> what could be different about the Files app on some devices as compared to say, the photo browser?

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:documentLaunchMode="never">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- react-native-share-menu -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

**THIS IS THE LOGS FROM THE 'working' intent**

03-25 11:16:39.502   672  4613 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=application/pdf flg=0xb080001 cmp=com.geo.geoop.dev/com.geo.MainActivity clip={application/pdf U:content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/3875} (has extras)} from uid 10117, pid -1
03-25 11:16:39.520   672  4613 I ActivityManager: Ignoring FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT, launchMode is "singleInstance" or "singleTask"
03-25 11:16:39.547   672  4613 I ActivityManager: ->startActivity for ActivityRecord{60fe743 u0 com.geo.geoop.dev/com.geo.MainActivity t44} result:START_TASK_TO_FRONT

**This is the logs from the intent that resets my activity state**
03-25 11:24:49.029   672  1654 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=application/pdf flg=0x13000001 pkg=com.geo.geoop.dev cmp=com.geo.geoop.dev/com.geo.MainActivity clip={application/pdf U:content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/3876} (has extras)} from uid 10309, pid 11323
03-25 11:24:49.057   672  1654 I ActivityManager: ->startActivity for ActivityRecord{88d66b2 u0 com.geo.geoop.dev/com.geo.MainActivity t47} result:START_TASK_TO_FRONT

The only difference I can see is the flags.  There are a few different ones between the two:

**the working version has these**

0x00080000 FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET
0x08000000 FLAG_RECEIVER_NO_ABORT
0x04000000 FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

**the not working version has these flags**

0x10000000 FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
0x02000000 FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT

Im now delving into the code of the sharing library my RN app is using to receive the share Intent. The behaviour I was seeing is that if the app was launched from a share intent from Google Files, then it would crash/hang during startup. If it was brought to the foreground by Google Files, then it would appear in its resumed state, then 'reset' and become unusable. After looking at the library code recieving the intent, I found the code below - This is what 'resets' my app state, causing the issues. I removed it, and the app no longer crash/hangs after launch.

However, that code is there for a reason. The behaviour without it, results in the Files app becoming associated with my app, such that its launch icon of my app appears as the icon of the files app, and if I click the files icon , it brings my app to the front.

```
 public void getSharedText(Callback successCallback) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

    if (currentActivity == null) {
      return;
    }

    // If this isn't the root activity then make sure it is
    if (!currentActivity.isTaskRoot()) {
      Intent newIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.getIntent());
      newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      currentActivity.startActivity(newIntent);

      ReadableMap shared = extractShared(newIntent);
      successCallback.invoke(shared);
      clearSharedText();
      currentActivity.finish();
      return;
    }

    Intent intent = currentActivity.getIntent();

    ReadableMap shared = extractShared(intent);
    successCallback.invoke(shared);
    clearSharedText();
  }
```

thanks for any help with this, Im not an android expert by any means, and this has me scratching my head

Comment: What is it that you do? Sharing. Another app shares files to your app? And that other app uses a react  native share menu? What is going on?

Comment: You might have edited your post but you did not answer all questions. Any reason?

Comment: @blackapps OK - on a mobile phone when you look at an image or PDF for example in a file browser, you can share that file with any other apps on the phone that have registered with the OS to accept them.  The user will choose the app they wish to share with, and then typically that app will be invoked and the user will interact with that target app to do whatever they want to do the file.

Comment: react-native-share-menu is a react native library that does the registration with the OS, and accepts the shared content from the native OS and passes it to your RN javascript code.

Comment: My specific issue is with android.  Sharing invokes my app by an intent of some kind, but not in a happy functional state.

Comment: As your app is not sharing a file but only receiving a file i was confused you speaked about a share menu as a share menu would belong to a sharing app. Not to your app. Well apparently i was wrong. Sorry. And sorry i cant help you with that.

Comment: updated after more experimenting.  The behaviour is something specific to do with the way the android 'Files' app shares -> other apps dont cause my app to 'reset' its activity or whatever it is that is happening.  It retains its state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140805/google-files-not-respecting-singleinstance-launchmode#comment137760008_78140805

Comment: Im now delving into the code of the sharing library my RN app is using to receive the share Intent.  The behaviour I was seeing is that if the app was launched from a share intent from Google Files, then it would crash/hang during startup.  If it was brought to the foreground by Google Files, then it would appear in its resumed state, then 'reset' and become unusable.   After looking at the library code recieving the intent, I found the code added to the OP above - This is what 'resets'  my app state, causing the issues.  I removed it, and the app no longer crash/hangs after launch.

Comment: However, that code is there for a reason.  The behaviour without it, results in the Files app becoming associated with my app, such that its launch icon of my app appears as the icon of the files app, and if I click the files icon , it brings my app to the front.  Time for a deep dive into Android intents to learn how to modify this code to eliminate all undesirable behaviour, but if anyone can help speed up that process, thanks!

Comment: Looks like this has been going on for ages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750124/launchmode-being-overriden-by-google-files-app-when-sharing-new-instance-of-a-s  and that the author of the share library has followed the advice in this issue - but that is playing havoc with my react native app.

Comment: Hmm, and complaing direct to facebook about react native app  same thing.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39553